# Swift / is there any equivalent to UITableViewRowAction for a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView with a button within a cell. I want the User to share the UIImage Image that is inside the CollectionViewCell.

At the Moment I have this code:

```
class EventsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var eventsImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func cellDetailButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alertView.title = "Alert!"
    alertView.message = "Message"
    alertView.delegate = self
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alertView.show()

}
```

I use this code for a tableView within another project, but I don't know how to use  it in a CollectionViewCell:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let shareRaceAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Share") {
        (action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in

        let sheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Teilen mit", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let race = self.races[indexPath.row]

        //
        let twAction = self.newAction(SLServiceTypeTwitter, race: race)
        sheet.addAction(twAction)

        //
        let fbAction = self.newAction(SLServiceTypeFacebook, race: race)
        sheet.addAction(fbAction)

        //
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        sheet.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    shareRaceAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [shareRaceAction]
}
```

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Your question's title should reflect the problem your facing not the technologies used. Please review [ask] and update your title.